# NetBeans not finding JasperReports scriptlet

Tags: netbeans, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports 3.7.6 with NetBeans 6.9.1 and iReport 3.7.6.  I have a report that uses scriptlets.  When I run it from iReport everything is fine because I can tell iReport where to find the .jar file with the scriptlets.  When I run that same report from a JSF-2.0 application the fields that rely on the scriptlet are not being populated correctly - i.e. the scriptlet isn't being called.  I've tried putting the scriptlet in the project's library folder and I've tried copying the package containing the scriptlet into the project.  Neither has worked.  I'm not sure how I can get the report to call the scriptlets when it is run from my JSF project.  Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. What is it with me and rookie mistakes? I have my JSF project pulling the .jasper files from a specific locations. To that end I have my iReport compiling the reports to that particular file location. At some point in the past week I was fiddling with another report and didn't want it to go to the same location as my project reports ... so I changed the compile location in iReport. It was after that when I created all the scriptlet functionality. When I added the scriptlet functionality and compiled the reports, I forgot to change the compile location back to the project report folder.  The reports were compiling elsewhere.  So my project was using the old versions of the report files. Updating the compile location in iReport and recompiling the reports fixed the issue. The .jar file in my library works fine.